# Android Open Accessory simultaneous connection

Tags: android, android-open-accessory

I'm developing an AOA application. And i wonder if it's possible to maintain several simultaneous connections with AOA?
Is it possible?
Or only one application can use AOA in a time?

Answer (score 1):

While using AOA the android handset(or tablet) functions as USB device and the accessory as USB host. One USB device can only connect with one USB host at a time, therefore, supporting several simultaneous connections using AOA through your application is ruled out.

Comment: The question asked literally concerns multiple applications, not necessarily multiple accessories.

Answer (score 1):

Only one application can use AOA in a time.

Other app can communication with the AOA app.